# Kindle collections and books not synching properly

Tags: kindle-paperwhite, sync

I'm trying to organize my books and collections through the "Manage your content and devices" on the amazon.com website.  Frequently, I have success.  But recently I've been getting very frustrated.  The website shows things as they *should* be, but on my kindle things are not synched correctly.  The most common problem is that books I've moved from one collection, call it "Collection A", to another, "Collection B", are not being removed from "Collection A" as desired.  They do not show there any more on the amazon.com website.  No matter how many times I restart or hit the "sync my kindle" button on the kindle, things do not correct themselves.

Please note, I've got the most recent software on my kindle. I've made sure that I'm logged into wifi.  I've scoured the web, but all I seem to be able to find are website telling you the most basic things about how to sync things.  I can't find anything about more intransigent issues.

Comment: Me too experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you marked the option "Annotations Backup" under Settings Menu?

Comment: I believe this is a bug. Three people have reported this problem now: https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users/4753/a-ellett
https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users/11452/ramanarayanan
https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users/9853/thufir Not sure how Amazon handles bug reports.